# Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I keep getting the above error above on the Roster table when I run my script, what did I do wrong, please? Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE SHIFT (
    Shift_ID NUMBER(5),
    Shift_Type VARCHAR2(20), 
    Start_Time VARCHAR2(10), 
    End_Time VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_SHIFT PRIMARY KEY (Shift_ID, Start_Time, End_Time)
    -- CONSTRAINT CHECK_SHIFT_TYPE CHECK (SHIFT_Type IN ('Day', 'Night'))
    -- CONSTRAINT CHECK_TOTAL_HOURS CHECK (Total_Hours IN (6, 8, 12))
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ROSTER(
    Roster_ID NUMBER(5),
    Shift_Date DATE,
    Shift_End_Date DATE,
    Total_Hours NUMBER(2),
    Shift_ID NUMBER(5) REFERENCES SHIFT(Shift_ID),
    Start_Time VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES SHIFT(Start_Time),
    End_Time VARCHAR2(10) REFERENCES SHIFT(End_Time),
    Ward_ID NUMBER(5) REFERENCES WARD (Ward_ID),
    Ward_Name VARCHAR2(25) REFERENCES WARD (Ward_Name),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ROSTER PRIMARY KEY (Roster_ID)
);
```

Comment: A foreign key must reference a complete key (the primary key or unique constraint), not one of several columns.

Comment: BTW, never store date/time values in varchar2 columns. Use proper date/time data types instead,

Comment: @jarlh, Thank you for the kind corrections. My professor recommended doing it this way since Oracle Apex doesn't handle the Date or time input well at the Application level. It's weird, but I just thought I'm not the one with the doctorate degree lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to create a foreign key with multiple columns in it, or wish to name it, you can't use the column-level syntax... you have to add it as a `CONSTRAINT` at the end, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ROSTER(
    Roster_ID NUMBER(5),
    Shift_Date DATE,
    Shift_End_Date DATE,
    Total_Hours NUMBER(2),
    Shift_ID NUMBER(5),
    Start_Time VARCHAR2(10),
    End_Time VARCHAR2(10),
    Ward_ID NUMBER(5),
    Ward_Name VARCHAR2(25),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ROSTER PRIMARY KEY (Roster_ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ROSTER_SHIFT FOREIGN KEY (Shift_ID, Start_Time, End_Time) REFERENCES SHIFT(Shift_ID, Start_Time, End_Time)
);
```